# How to implement basic auth with spring boot?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to add basic authentication to my spring boot back end. What I have so far is an angular front end login page and some basic authentication set up. Right now it allows one user account with user:"user" and password:"password". I'd like to be able to have database to store user details in and everytime someone trys to login the backend can just look for those details in the database. My plan is to use DynamoDB how would I do this from the websecurityconfig class?

Backend

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

Controller

```
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value ="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "Content-type=application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*" }, consumes = "application/json")
    public boolean login(@RequestBody UserModel user) {
        System.out.println(user.getUsername());
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        return user.getUsername().equals("user") && user.getPassword().equals("password");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authToken = request.getHeader("Authorization")
          .substring("Basic".length()).trim();
        return () ->  new String(Base64.getDecoder()
          .decode(authToken)).split(":")[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already read this?: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Comment: Remove your `login` from the controller (spring security does all of that for you) and just add users to your database. Configure the jdbc based user details service.